# How do I write an XML payload into a CXF SOAP response?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss AS 6.1 and the included version of CXF, which I believe is 2.3.1.

I have a web service with two operations:  the first lets the client request some data.  It posts a message to a JMS queue and returns a ticket number.  A MDB picks up the message, processes the request, building an extract datbase table.

The second operation lets a web client submit a ticket and, if the processing is done, returns the results.

Now, the issue is this:  I would like for my MDB to build the results, then marshal them into XML using JAXB and store the XML in the database.  Therefore, when the second operation requests the data, I want to insert this XML from the database as the payload into the SOAP envelope.  (FWIW: I want to save the response already in the database in XML for two reasons:  1, to facilitate saving this denormalized data instead of creating multiple extract tables, and 2) so that the response can go out as quickly as possible.)

Now, I think I have to write a PhaseInterceptor to accomplish this, but if anyone can point me at an example that alters or writes out a SOAP payload, I would appreciate it.  Any JBoss-CXF specific examples would be great, but I think vanilla CXF examples will probably suffice.  I've run across examples to modify headers.  I need something very basic and written for a small child. :-)

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. In the application I'm writing I store XML in a repository. I then use JAXB to add it to the CXF response (as an unmarshaled Java object). CXF then uses JAXB to marshal the objects back to XML. Why not skip the unmarshaling followed by marshaling and add it straight to the response. You could definitely do it with interceptors. You would probably need to perform some schema validation on the XML as you're just dumping it into the response. I'll investigate when I get a chance if no-one else answers in the meantime.

Comment: I suggest you add java tag to make more people see your post and substitute acronyms like MDB and FWIW.